# "..references a null or transient value." (Bad design?) - at least one of two columns must not be null

Tags: database, nhibernate, model, mapping, fluent

A Brand has an Image (logo - not nullable). A Product has many Images. An Image must have *either* a Brand or a Product, but I can't use "not nullable" on either field because an image only belongs to one of them?

How would you map this kind of relationship?

Brand 1----1 Image *----1 Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So no matter what, an image will always have a Brand or a Product? Can a Brand have more than one image? In most cases Brand or Product is a one-to-many relationship with Image.

Meaning that a Product or a Brand at any given time can have an Image.

I'm not sure the way you worded makes a lot of sense. But usually in most cases an Image table would be a lookup table, and would necessarily have relationships to Product or Brand, but Brand or Product would have an ImageID column, hence the one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I guess I could create a lookup table - by that you mean a table which holds only key values and no extra information to link the images to either brands or products?

Comment: Yes exactly, you wouldn't even need other keys in it, only the Image information, and your Brands and Products table will reference your Image table with an key constraint if necessary.